# 720P Render Preset Makes Audio shorter than Video VSE

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I have a video that I'm trying to change the render preset to 720P instead of the 1920x1080.  When I click this preset, it makes the audio way shorter than the video so it's no longer lined up.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the *Format* presets in the *Output Properties* like **DVCPRO HD 720p** or **HDTV 720p**, they are not simply changing the image resolution and/or ratio. They also set a framerate of 24 fps.

So, if you have a video with a length of 60 seconds at 30 fps, than this video contains 1800 frames. The audio strip of the movie has a length of 60 seconds as well, which results in an audio strip of 1800 frames length.

If you now switch to the **HDTV 720p** preset, the framerate is set to 24 fps. The *Video Sequence Editor* works frame-based. Now your video has still 1800 frames, but at 24 fps that's 75 seconds.

The audio strip doesn't get stretched automatically, because the audio is time-based, not frame-based like the video strip. The audio stays at 60 seconds, which means it is now 15 seconds shorter than the video - and this results in a length of 24 × 60 = 1440 frames.

To make them match again, you have to set the fps back to the video's original framerate (in my example 30 fps) manually - which I would recommend, because I imagine things like animations are intended to be played back at the framerate they were created in order to make them look correctly.

You could also change the duration of the audio strip by changing the *Pitch*, but you still have to change the audio strip's frame range manually and it also makes the audio sound deeper. Changing the length without changing the pitch you have to do in a separate audio software.

[image: render format preset]